# Magento - How to create different weight-price drop down in products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

How can I build a drop down list with different weights with prices for a product, which can be selected by user. Something like this

[Example](http://bigbasket.com/pc/fruits-vegetables/vegetables/)

When user selects his required weight from the drop down the price also changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage this by creating `Custom Option` for the products in Magento

Comment: When you use the custom option and add different weights, like 250 grams and 500 grams, and give prices to it, the outcome(in the drop down) is like "250 grams + given price". And when selected the given price is added to the original price. But what I want is something like "250 grams is given price". It should not be added to the original price

Comment: Here are some solutions for this:

http://magentoabid.blogspot.in/2014/09/magento-custom-options-change-option-to.html 

http://freemagentotips.blogspot.in/2014/01/magento-custom-options-change-option-to.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/use-absolute-price-for-custom-options